# How to instantiate a class one time and access it in views

Tags: django

I have a class that runs once, which I had in `myapp/__init__.py`, but each time django starts it would run twice. It also runs when I migrate models, when I don't need it to.

I've read about the *ready* function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready, but cannot access the instantiated class outside of apps.py

Here is my current workflow:
in **init**.py:

```
from .my_module import ResourceHeavyClass
resource_heavy_instance = ResourceHeavyClass()
```

in my views.py

```
from . import resource_heavy_instance
```

This currently works, but I only want to load the module when the server starts, not when I make migrations. Appreciate any tips/advice.

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate the class where you need it rather than in an init.py file.

Comment: Because I need it in views.py and each time I visit the site, the module will load. I'm trying to build a restful API that takes data from a form, modifies it and returns it

Comment: But if you instantiate it inside the actual view that is being fetched, rather than for the entire views.py, it won't affect migrations. Why do you need it already instantiated in views.py at global level?

Comment: That means it will reload the module each time I refresh the page of the view and it takes about 30 seconds each time.

Comment: @huntoperator no it won't. Items defined at module level, in views.py or anywhere else, are only loaded once per process.\

Comment: @DanielRoseman - in my case I was able to confirm it does reload the class each time I hit refresh if I instantiate it inside of the view function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a [**`SimpleLazyObject`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/utils/functional/) to postpone the creation until you really need it. Like for example:

```
from .my_module import ResourceHeavyClass
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject

class SomeClass:

    resource_heave_instance = SimpleLazyObject(ResourceHeavyClass)
```

Now as long as you do *not* fetch the `SomeClass.resource_heave_instance`, it will not create the `ResourceHeavyClass`.

So if you for example have a method, you can use it like:

```
def some_method():
    resource_heave_instance = SomeClass.resource_heave_instance
```

So here, when you *call* the `some_method`, it fetches the attribute, and it will indeed construct the object. But as long as the attribute is not fetched, it will not create a `ResourceHeavyClass` object. Once constructed, it will not create the object a second time.

So if the attribute is *not* fetched by just interpreting the file (so only by calling functions, and other continuations), we are safe.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Should I post some_method in views.py?

Comment: @huntoperator: `some_method` is just a method that makes use of tis `ResourceHeavyClass`, so if you want to use that in one of your views/models/..., that's fine.

Comment: I tried wrapping the ResourceHeavyClass with a SimpleLazyObject, each time I run python manage.py makemigrations it still runs the ResourceHeavyInstance

Comment: @huntoperator: then it is likely that something not wrapped in a *continuation* accesses the attribute.

Comment: @huntoperator: also note that this should be `SimpleLazyObject(ResourceHeavyClass)` *not* `SimpleLazyObject(ResourceHeavyClass())`. The `SimpleLazyObject` expects a callable, not an object.

Comment: Thank you, Willem. I applied SimpleLazyObject to __init__.py and reference the ResourceHeavy Class in my view. It takes a little bit to load the first time, but works great thereafter and I don't need to load the module each time I run a migration.